# How to avoid "The following applications should be closed" message during uninstallation with WIX?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I try to write an MSI installer using WIX. During uninstallation I need to run a specialized custom action that first stops my services and then closes the application. I do that after `InstallInitialize` event using the following mark-up:

```
<CustomAction Id='myCustomAction' BinaryKey='myDll' DllEntry='msiUninstallInitialize' Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no' />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='myCustomAction' After='InstallInitialize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The issue is that if a previous version of my application was running before I try to upgrade to a newer one using my MSI, I was getting a [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) popping up this message:

[image]

and then this one:

[image]

To stop it from doing it, I added the following property:

```
<Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />
```

But now the uninstaller shows this window:

[image]

So I was curious, is there any way to disable checks if my app is running (I will close it myself during my custom action processing)?

Comment: did u find the solution?

Comment: @kudlatiger: No. Not thru MSI/Wix. I ended up making a DLL that was included in the MSI that I could invoke my exported C++ function from during un-installation phase. And that's where I was able to close all open applications from.

Answer (score 5):

You've disabled the Restart Manager interaction with the Windows Installer so now the Windows Installer is falling back to its old behavior, FileInUse dialog. This behavior is documented with  [MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I've never tried but theory has it that you can make your FilesInUse dialog hidden (`Dialog/@Hidden='yes'`) to cause the dialog to not be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it's been 6 months as I asked it. So if I write another Wix installer I'll give it a try....

Comment: If useful can you mark the question answered so it falls off my queries of "unanswered wix questions". :)

Comment: Just for the sake of accuracy, I need to make sure it actually solves my issue before I do that. So sorry, if it messes you up. At this point I can only upvote it. Although I do appreciate your help and overall what you're doing with Wix!

Comment: I have tried to make the FilesInUse dialog hidden but this is not the same dialog that is presented as the one c00000fd has posted in his last image, and does not work.

Comment: hiding the dialog will solve the issue? will it kill the service during uninstallation?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to move your Custom Action that stops your services & processes before the **Preparing** step in your *Install Execution Stage*.

Per AdvancedInstaller's docs (emphasis mine):

> Preparing - Verifies all volumes for sufficient space for the installation. **Checks and notifies the user if any installation files are in use.** You can set the deferred, rollback or commit flag for actions after this group. These are executed by Finish Execution action group. You can run them elevated by using the "with no impersonation" flags.

It's important to note that you cannot use the "with no impersonation" flags on these custom actions, however.

Comment: Tried this, but I'm still getting the "The following applications should be closed.." dialog