# How to rebuild WiX library, i.e. trying to get rid of FilesInUse dialog?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to get rid of Restart Manager or FilesInUse dialogs in my MSI project written with WiX. My first step was to add the following tag:

```
<Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />
```

It got rid of RM, but it made the FilesInUse dialog pop up instead. There's not many resources available on the web on this subject. I found [this old thread](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-disable-bypass-FilesInUse-dialog-td2685146.html) that gives some details. The author at the end said that he had to rebuild WiX with a modified `wix36-sources\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\FilesInUse.wxs` file.

So how do you rebuild WiX? And, am I even on the right track?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid "The following applications should be closed" message during uninstallation with WIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823503/how-to-avoid-the-following-applications-should-be-closed-message-during-uninst)

Answer (score 0):

WiX provides a few dialog sets. You must be using one of them. If you don't like what they do, don't use them. WiX makes it easy to define your own. You don't need to rebuild WiX to author your own UI.

If you mostly like one of WiX's dialog sets, use it as a template. The message you referenced links to an [example](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2008/08/customised-uis-for-wix.html) of just that. It does say to download the WiX source. That's only because you'll probably want to copy and paste most of a dialog set that you like.

Comment: I don't know Wix that well. Can someone explain without giving me links to what I already saw? I managed to do what he is referring to in that article but now I got two problems: one, my MSI now runs with a bunch of UI windows that I don't need, and two, the FileInUse dialog still shows and I can't seem to customize it even though I can customize all the other UI... Very frustrating!